# Determining the matching number of a graph given maximal matchings.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph with maximal matchings $M_1$ and $M_2$, with $3$ and $6$ edges, respectively. Determine the matching number of $G$.

The only progress I've been able to make is that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are edge disjoint owing to the fact that $|M_2|=2|M_1|$. I'm thinking it has to do with the larger matching being an augmenting path of the smaller matching. Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the biggest difference in sizes of two maximal matchings?

Comment: @TysonWilliams The largest had ought to be the size of the smaller matching, right? Because each of the edges of one maximal matching can be adjacent to at most two edges in the other maximal matching, so at most the second is twice the size of the first. I get the sense that this implies that the larger of the matchings is maximum, and in this case, the matching number is 6.

Comment: Yes, on the right track.